# Testing a rack app

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, rack

I have a rack based gem, where the user defines routes, and they are then processed by the gem. I an trying to figure out how to test this setup. Testing methods directly impacted by the creation of routes doesn't work, because they are obviously not defined yet, because no app has been created. Is there a solution to this? I am currently using RSpec, and I would really like it if there is an RSpec solution to this.

Comment: I think adding specifics could make this question more comprehensible. What gem is it?

Comment: I'm still writing it.